# Dropbox CLI syncing issues

Tags: linux, command-line, dropbox

I have (only) SSH access to a remote server, on which I installed Dropbox and the CLI as per these instructions: http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/install-dropbox-in-an-entirely-text-based-linux-environment

It worked as expected until a server restart recently. As of now, it gives the impression that it is functioning:

> $ ~/dropbox.py start
>
> Starting Dropbox...Done!
>
> $ ~/dropbox.py status
>
> Up to date

... but any changes made to Dropbox are not syncing. New directories or files do not upload to the cloud and are not registered via the web interface or other synced devices. Furthermore, and perhaps most indicative of the problem, I get this output from *filestatus*:

> $ ~/dropbox.py filestatus
>
> Drummer Man.psd:  unwatched
>
> ScrabbleDEMF.psd: unwatched
>
> Walken.psd:       unwatched

... etc. for ALL files and directories in my Dropbox folder.

To troubleshoot, I unlinked the Dropbox from my account, backed up and deleted .dropbox, and then reinstalled both Dropbox itself as well as the CLI. At which point, I successfully downloaded all of my Dropbox's contents (as some folders were previously excluded from sync) demonstrating that it was in fact connected and syncing.

I have found no other evidence of this happening to others besides one post on Stack Overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25849077/dropboxd-on-linux-server-has-stopped-syncing), where the "solution" was as follows:

> Upgrading to the newest version of dropboxd and the python script and restarting seemed to fix it

Unless I am going about it wrong, this did not do anything.

Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am in the exact same situation.  I have to reinstall the whole thing to get it to go back to syncing.

I had not put together that server restarts have anything to do with it.  I'll reach out to my sysadmin and see if that makes sense.  at this point I'm ready to abandon dropbox as a solution entirely.